# Casting Anonymous Type LINQ Using TryCast Returns Nothing

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want my query to return a List (Of Service) then I want to use the new list to further filter.

When I run this query it exectutes correctly

```
Dim duplicateService = svgGrpContainer.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ServiceGroup).Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).Select(Function(x) x)
```

I am now attempting to cast it in oder to use it and create another query

```
    Dim duplicatePAK = duplicateServiceGroups.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Name).Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).Select(Function(x) x)
```

When I cast the first query it now returns Nothing

```
 Dim duplicateService As List(Of ServiceGroup) = TryCast(svgGrpContainer.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ServiceGroup).Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).Select(Function(x) x), List(Of ServiceGroup))
```

ToList throws a grouping exception I tried that.

How do I cast the query so I can further filter the data in subsequent queries? Or Use 1 query and group by both Group and Name?

Comment: how a `ServiceGroup` is said to be duplicate in `svgGrpContainer`? for example this `Name ` property, if it is repeating then it means duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a .net fiddle with a working solution (forgive the C#).

c#: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pUqNSS
vb.net: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aixeIB

You need to use an anonymous object to group by multiple fields and then a SelectMany to flatten your list.

The main idea is

```
    Dim duplicates As List(Of Thing) = 
        things.
            GroupBy(Function(thing) New With {Key .Name = thing.Name, Key .ServiceGroup = thing.ServiceGroup }).
            Where(Function(group) group.Count() > 1).
            SelectMany(Function(group) group.ToList).
            ToList()
```

Comment: I want only the ones with the same group and name. Can you show this in vb.net I am having trouble converting

Comment: @NickLaMarca Sure, one sec.

Comment: I am getting a compile error..Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of m02Auth.ServiceGroup))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of m02Auth.ServiceGroup)'

Comment: Hmm, might be my vb.net (I'm a c# guy).  Let me update the fiddle as well to make sure it works.

Comment: If I keep it anonymous it compiles and works. Thanks

Comment: @NickLaMarca Got the vb.net fiddle working.  One thing to note, I missed a Key on the service group in my original answer

Answer (score 0):

You get an `IEnumerable<T>` after doing LINQ operations. Try using `.ToList()` instead, but you have a grouping which you'll have to figure out what needs to be done there - thats up to your logic to decide.

Comment: Can I somehow just group by Group and Name in 1 query?

Answer (score 0):

The inner query is currently returning an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping(Of ServiceGroup, T)`, which is why it won't cast to `IEnumerable(Of ServiceGroup)`. Instead of selecting the entire `IGrouping`, select the `Key` of each group. That should give you an `IEnumerable(Of ServiceGroup)`...

```
Dim duplicateService As List(Of ServiceGroup) = svgGrpContainer.
                                            GroupBy(Function(x) x.ServiceGroup).
                                            Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).
                                            Select(Function(x) x.Key).
                                            ToList()
```

Comment: I believe what he wants is a `List(of Service)`. You could possible select `x.ToList()` but that would give you a `IEnumerable(of List(of Service))` and destroy the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

The `GroupBy` method does not return an `IEnumerable(of T)`, it returns an `IEnumerable(of IGrouping(of TKey, T))`

In your case, what you're getting out of your initial query is `IEnumerable(of IGrouping(of ServiceGroup, Service))`, where each `IGrouping` is itself a list of `Service` objects grouped by your `ServiceGroup` as the key.

You have a couple of options here, depending on your goal with your second query (which also groups).

One option is to use `SelectMany` on the first query to "flatten" the list; this will get your back an `IEnumerable(of Service)` but you will lose the grouping by `ServiceGroup` in the process. That may be ok: if you were only using the first group to filter by the `Count` and don't need it anymore, this option should work for you. I believe it would be as simple as this (since `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`):

```
Dim duplicateService = svgGrpContainer.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ServiceGroup).Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).SelectMany(Function(x) x)
```

If what you're trying to accomplish is to get your services grouped by `ServiceGroup`, then grouped by `Name` within each service group, I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do that in two separate queries. Personally I'd probably just loop through my first results and build up the second set of groups one at a time, since it would be a lot clearer than whatever LINQ mess you'd come up with. If you really need that result, let me know and I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: All I want is a result that has the same group and name